# Is there any utility like the Windows program smartcopy?

Tags: software-recommendation, clipboard

It should help me pause copying, so I dont have to wait for each copy to finish. Basic googling didnt help out. The windows equivalent is Teracopy, or Fastcopy.

I need the application to be GUI based, but wouldn't mind shell commands.

I wait for the copy to finish, in cases where I copy to the same destination, like a pen-drive, where throughput is in the order of 5 MB/s.

Answer (score 6):

If you're doing copies from the command line, `rsync` will optimize the copies about as much as is possible and you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to pause it, then type `fg` to resume.

Comment: Ctrl + Z is the way to do it. It's equivalent to sending the SIGSTOP signal to the process. To resume, run `fg` (foreground), which matches the SIGCONT signal.

Comment: I think someone's trying to tel me staying up all night wasn't such a hot idea...

Comment: I didn't know that you could pause rsync in this manner; that's really, really useful. Thanks!

Comment: @Windigo: You can pause almost anything in this manner.

Answer (score 3):

[MiniCopier](http://www.adriancourreges.com/projects/minicopier/)

> MiniCopier is a graphical copy manager. It provides more comfort and control over files copy operations, than basic OS functions.
>   With MiniCopier it is possible to queue different transfers, resume a copy that has failed, limit the speed or pause the copy. If a transfer fails, an error is logged and the rest of the queue is treated.

[Ultracopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/)

> Ultracopier is an advanced and yet easy to use portable application designed to enable users to copy or move files and folders with a few clicks. This tool was developed to provide speed limitation, error / colision management, translation and many more interesting features. Available in many languages & as a portable version.

Answer (score 1):

When copying files with the default file manager `Nautilus`, you don't need to wait for files to finish copying. It doesn't even slow down like Windows does when you initiate multiple simultaneous operations to the same disk like Windows does. With the command line equivalent `cp`, you really don't need to wait for it finish either. Put an ampersand at the end of your copy command and it will run in the background. If you started one already taht you wish to run in the background, press ctrl-z, then issue the `bg` command.

`gadmin-rsync` is a graphical front end to `rsync`  if you wish use rsync ...rsynch is expecially good if you're copying somethin between machines that has already been copied before. Only the delta is transferred. The caveat with this is that you need rsync installed on the source and the target machine to get the 'delta' transfer capability. You can of course use the rsync command line rather than the gui.

Comment: I know I don't have to wait for the first to finish, (I have to re-word better), it is a problem when I copy to the same destination, usually a pen-drive.

Comment: I don't find I the total throughput to flash drives slows down in Linux.. I know if you copy 1 file in Windows and it says it will take 2 minutes and immediately copy another file of the same size to the same target, it will end up taking about 30 to copy both files. In Linux I find it's quite linear, and would take 4 minutes in the example I've described here.